# Android: Adding Background on a Custom TextView class

Tags: android, android-canvas, textview

I want to have a background of my TextView class, but I don't know how. I try to use the onDraw method on the class but it is not working.

Here is my code for my custom TextView class.

```
public class Balls extends TextView{

public Balls(Context context) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.setText("ball");
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    canvas.drawCircle(50, 50,30, paint);
}}
```

Any idea how can I fix this code? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set Background in following way,

```
public class Balls extends TextView{

    public Balls(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setText("ball");
        this.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.imageName);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawCircle(50, 50,30, paint);
    }
}
```

I used

```
 this.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.imageName);
```

in constructor to set Background Image.Also you can set background color in same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try [setBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackground%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) or [setBackgroundResource](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29)

Comment: Thank you. I use setBackgroundResource for adding background of my TextView. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See [Scale Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Scale) and [Shape Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)